# IOS9 Video Scrubbing

Tags: ios, video-editing

In IOS8 it was possible to scrub through videos without first pressing the play button.   In IOS9 it seems that the only way to access the scrubbing tool is to first start playing the video and then the scrubbing tool becomes available.

Anyone with a workaround for getting to scrubbing quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the small thumb at the bottom to expand the scrubbing tool.

Comment: Right you are.    Very small target on iphone,  but thumbnail between white bar does indeed produce desired result!